# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\n_\lodash-3.*.tgz'

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to setup this program to run on my PC >
https://github.com/BitMEX/api-connectors/tree/master/official-ws/delta-server

I did all the steps, but when I run "node index.js" I get

```
"Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'"
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\official-ws\delta-server\api-connectors\official- 
ws\nodejs\index.js:2:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

So I asked some people on discord, and they told me everything is already setup, I just need to run "npm install -g _n"

So I ran that and I get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\n_\lodash-3.*.tgz'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! n_@1.4.6 postinstall: `npm pack lodash@^3 && targz extract lodash- 
3.*.tgz extraneous/lodash3`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the n_@1.4.6 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09- 
15T00_37_09_934Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

my question is solved, I had a weird file path that was retarded. now it works.

bad file path > C:\official-ws\delta-server\api-connectors\official-ws\delta-server

good file path > C:\api-connectors\official-ws\delta-server